# sqlplus resultproperty

Tags: oracle, ant, sqlplus

I am trying to run an sql file having select count from an sql table and store it in a variable using sqlplus in ant.

```
ora:sqlplus  dir="${basedir}" start="${sql_count_table_name}.sql" silent="true"
  logon="${sql_username}/${sql_password}@${sql_database}" 
  failonerror="false" resultproperty="tablecount">
</ora:sqlplus
```

But table count is not getting assigned to the variable tablecount.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://incanto.sourceforge.net/usage-sqlplus.html), `resultProperty` is:

> Name of a property in which the return code of the command should be
>   stored

... so it will get the exit code from SQL*Plus, not a value you queried. If your script had multiple queries, or a query with multiple columns, what would would you expect it set it to?

You could perhaps subvert the exit status to achieve this, using the SQL*Plus `COLUMN` command's [`NEW_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref799) syntax to create a substitution variable:

```
column table_count new_value my_exit_code
select count(*) as table_count from ...
exit &my_exit_code
```

... but you'd lose any ability to detect a real error.

---

**Edit**: I'd forgotten that the exit code is limited; from [the SQL*Plus documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve023.htm):

> The range of operating system return codes is also restricted on some
>   operating systems. This limits the portability of EXIT n and EXIT
>   variable between platforms. For example, on UNIX there is only one
>   byte of storage for return codes; therefore, the range for return
>   codes is limited to zero to 255.

So unless you're always expecting a really small count, this won't work, and as it will mod the value you can't even rely on zero/non-zero being meaningful.

You may not actually care about the count; you may just be testing for the existence of something, in which case you could do something like:

```
select least(count(*), 1) as table_count from ...
```

... which would give you an exit code of 0 if there are no rows, and 1 if there any.